# My code runs with no errors but it runs only a section of the code (C Language)

Tags: c, printf, scanf

i´m trying to make an algorithm to find the weighted mean of a student's grades (from 0 to 10) which gets 4 inputs: name, grade1, grade2, grade3 in vs code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float grade1, grade2, grade3, weightedaverage;
  char studentname[50];

  printf("\nType the name of the student: ");
  fgets(studentname, 50, stdin);

  printf("\nType the first grade: ");
  scanf("%f", grade1);

  printf("\nType the second grade: ");
  scanf("%f", grade2);

  printf("\nType the third grade: ");
  scanf("%f", grade3);

  weightedaverage = (grade1 *2) + (grade2 *4) + (grade3 *6) / 12;
  // 

  printf("\nNAME: %s\nWEIGHTED AVERAGE: %f", studentname, weightedaverage);

  return(0);
}
```

Well, the problem is when i run, it only executes until the input of the first "type your first grade" line, and then it stops running, like it justs show after that the path of where the program is located. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does it compile without warnings and errors? If so, find out how to enable warnings (eg: `-Wall` for gcc and clang) because modern compilers will tell you the problem with this code (that `scanf("%f", ___)` expects a pointer to float, not a float).

Comment: The shown code cannot output "type your first grade". You need to make sure that you build and run the code you are looking at.

Comment: Please quote the warnings you get when compiling that code. Explain what you do not understand about them. Read docu of `scanf()`, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf especially on what kind of parameters are expected, especially in contrast to `printf()`. Maybe try to follow a tutorial on reading input with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic error, always use & in scanf  `scanf("%f", &grade3);`